# How does the foldr function in haskell work in this case?

Tags: haskell, fold

So I'm new to haskell and I kind of encountered this following expression which i don't quiet get how it works:
`foldr (.) (+3) [(*2), (+5)] 13`
it gives out the result: 42
now i know that `foldr` normally works in an example like: `foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]` like: `(1+(2+(0+3)))` but with adding another function `(.)` I kind of got confused.
So please if any of you could explain to me exactly how haskell interprets this expression that would be great, thanks!

Comment: `foldr (.) (+3) [(*2), (+5)]` is `(*2) . (+5) . (+3)`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the quick response :) ok now that i understand, but when we change the `foldr` to `foldl`, is it still the same thing then or does the order change? Thanks again!

Comment: @AchrafRAGUI: no, the it is `(+3) . (*2) . (+5)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That was my guess also for that, but then i don't  quiet get the order of the `foldr`, because with `foldl` it makes sense, since it goes from left to right, but with `foldr` it doesn't go from right to left: like `(+5) . (*2) . (+3)`. Can you please explain to me that a bit more? I really appreciate it

Comment: `foldl` conceptually works left-to-right, and replaces the empty list (the end of the list) with `z`. `foldr` works right-to-left.

Comment: @AchrafRAGUI The difference between `foldl` and `foldr` is `((((+3)) . (*2)) . (+5))` vs `((*2) . ((+5) . ((+3))))`, not the direction of the list traversal. To achieve that, you'd `reverse` the list or `flip` the `(.)` combinator.

Comment: @Bergi ah ok that makes much more sense now. Thanks so much for the explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments might have already solved this for you. However, if not:

(.) is function composition:

```
f . g
= \x -> f $ g $ x
= \x -> f (g x).
```

Forms like `(* 2)` are sugar for functions of the form `\x -> x * 2`

Now, observe that

```
foldr op base [a,b]
```

is the same as

```
a `op` (b `op` base)
```

of course, this works for higher numbers of arguments as well. For instance,

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

is just

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0
```

In your case, you ask about

```
foldr (.) (+3) [(*2), (+5)]
```

which is (for `Integer`)

```
(*2) . (+5) . (+3)
= \x -> (*2) $ (+5) $ (+3) $ x
= \x -> (*2) $ (+5) $ x + 3
= \x -> (*2) $ x + 3 + 5
= \x -> (x + 3 + 5) * 2
= \x -> x*2 + 16
```

and so

```
foldr (.) (+3) [(*2), (+5)] 13
= (\x -> x*2 + 16) 13
= 13*2 + 16
= 26 + 16
= 42
```

Answer (score 2):

`foldr f z` can be seen as replacing the "cons" `(:)` of the list with `f`, and the empty list with `z`. This thus means that `foldr f z [x1, x2 … xn]` is equivalent to `f x1 (f x2 ( … (f xn z) … ))`

`[(*2), (+5)]` is syntactical sugar for `(:) (*2) ((:) (+5)  [])`, so we can replace this with: `(.) (*2) ((.) (+5)  (+3))`, which is a verbose form of `(*2) . (+5) . (+3)`. This is thus a function. If we make a function application with this function and `13` as argument, we get:

```
   ((*2) . (+5) . (+3)) 13
-> ((*2) . (+5)) 16
-> (*2) 21
-> 42
```

`foldl f z [x1, x2 … xn]` is equivalent to `f (… (f (f z x1) x2) … ) xn`. So here that means `foldl (.) (+3) [(*2), (+5)]` is equivalent to `(.) ((.) (+3) (*2)) (+5)`, or less verbose `(+3) . (*2) . (+5)`. If we evaluate this for `13`, we obtain:

```
   ((+3) . (*2) . (+5)) 13
-> ((+3) . (*2)) 18
-> (+3) 36
-> 39
```

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell (and in lambda calculus) you can do [Eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion)

In the example you shown, the long way to write would be:

```
foldr (\f h -> f . h) (\x -> x+3) [(\x -> x*2), (\x->x+5)] 13
```

Now you can apply Eta reduction one by one like this:

```
(\f h -> f . h)
(\f -> (f.))
(.)
```

next:

```
(\x -> x+3)
(+3)
```

(\x -> x*2), (\x->x+5) are so similar to (+3)

so finally you get you equivalent expression:

```
foldr (.) (+3) [(*2), (+5)]
```

and that means, compose each function, and when the list is empty, apply (+3)